# Simplify the following expression $\sum_{j=0}^n 2^n \binom{1/2}{n-j}\binom{j-1/2}{j}$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

Simplify the following expression $\sum_{j=0}^n 2^n \binom{1/2}{n-j}\binom{j-1/2}{j}$ to something without a summutation mark (and probably elementary).

The question originates from the $n$th term of the polynomial expansion of $\sqrt{\frac{1+2x}{1-2x}}$, i.e. the coefficient of $x^n$ in its Maclaurin series.

We define $\binom{r}{n}=\frac{a(a-1)(a-2)...(a-b+1)}{b!}$ where $r$ is any real number and $n$ is a natural number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We already know for $n\geq 0$:

\begin{align*}
\sum_{j=0}^n 2^n \binom{1/2}{n-j}\binom{j-1/2}{j}=[x^n]\sqrt{\frac{1+2x}{1-2x}}\tag{1}
\end{align*}

> We obtain from (1)
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{j=0}^n}&\color{blue}{ 2^n \binom{1/2}{n-j}\binom{j-1/2}{j}}\\
> &=[x^n]\sqrt{\frac{1+2x}{1-2x}}\\
> &=[x^n]\frac{1+2x}{\sqrt{1-4x^2}}\tag{2}\\
> &=[x^n]\left(1+2x\right)\sum_{j=0}^\infty\binom{-\frac{1}{2}}{j}\left(-4x^2\right)^j\tag{3}\\
> &=\left([x^n]+2[x^{n-1}]\right)\sum_{j=0}^\infty\binom{-\frac{1}{2}}{j}(-4)^jx^{2j}\tag{4}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=}\begin{cases}
> \color{blue}{\binom{-\frac{1}{2}}{m}(-4)^m}&\qquad\color{blue}{ n=2m}\\
> \tag{5}\\
> \color{blue}{2\binom{-\frac{1}{2}}{m}(-4)^m}&\qquad\color{blue}{ n=2m+1}
> \end{cases}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (2) we  expand   the fraction with $1+2x$.
- In (3) we apply the *[binomial series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)*.
- In (4) we use $[x^{p-q}]A(x)=[x^p]x^qA(x)$.
- In (5) we select the coefficient of $x^n$ for even and odd $n$.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like $$2\binom{n-1}{\lfloor(n-1)/2\rfloor}-[n=0].$$  See [OEIS A063886](https://oeis.org/A063886).

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by $-[n=0]$? Thanks

Comment: It is the [Iverson bracket](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket).